# Problem with Active Item in angular tablist

Tags: css, angular

i have issue with active class in tablist/listgroup of angular. when i click any items it becomes  active,but active class is not being removed from old tab. Please help me out

[image]

```
<div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
                <span *ngFor="let itm of serviceitms;let i = index">
                <a *ngIf="i == 0" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list"
                    href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="itm.name">{{itm.name}}</a>
                    <a *ngIf="i != 0" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list"
                    href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="itm.name">{{itm.name}}</a>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you provide demo for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using angular with bootstrap directly. Use ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap angular should not be directly used with bootstrap. That is a very bad practice.

ng-bootstrap option:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview

ngx-bootstrap option (combine groups with accordion):

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/buttons
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion

Answer (score 0):

i think you should change the id and href for every item.

also you should do this for tab content divs.

```
<div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
    <span *ngFor="let itm of serviceitms;let i = index">
        <a [class.active]="i == 0" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-home-list{{ i }}" data-toggle="list"
                href="#list-home{{ i }}" role="tab" aria-controls="itm.name">{{itm.name}}</a>
    </span>
</div>
```